# MongoDB - Most Recent Item for Each ID in List

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of content IDs and I’m trying to fetch the most recent comment (if one exists) for each of the content IDs in the list -

My query looks as follows:

```
const query = [
   { 
      $match: { 
         content_id: { $in: myContentIds }, 
      }, 
   }, 
   { $sort: { ‘comment_created’: -1 } }, 
]

const results = await collection.find(query).toArray();
```

My understanding is this will fetch all of the comments related to the contentIds in the `myContentIds` array and sort them in descending order based on the date.

I could then limit my results using `{ $limit: 1}` but this would return the most recent comment on any of the content items, rather than the most recent comment for each content.

How can I modify my query to return the most recent comment for each of my content items?

Comment: can you show example document and expected result.

Comment: A comment will have a `content_id` and a `comment_created` date field . `myContentIds` will be an array of ids, for example `[1,3,5,82]`. The expected result is an array of comments, so for example: `[{comment_id: 123,  content_id: 3, comment_created: ‘2020-12-10T09:21:48.861Z`}, {comment_id: 1256,  content_id: 5, comment_created: ‘2020-11-10T09:31:48.861Z`}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$group` by `content_id` and get first recent document
- `$replaceRoot` to replace that recent document in root (this is optional, you can use document by object `recentComment`)

```
const query = [
  { $match: { content_id: { $in: myContentIds } } },
  { $sort: { comment_created: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$content_id",
      recentComment: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$recentComment" } }
];

const results = await collection.aggregate(query);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PvtYl8OymG-)